# ZFS CIFS shares, clients can't see mount points of other shares in root folder?

Tags: windows, solaris, zfs, cifs, share

I'm in the process of migrating data from a Win2k3 file server to a box running Solaris. All was going well until I started coming across nested shares. An example of this is a share that the photocopiers use to drop scanned documents into, this shared folder is located in the general staff data share. This works fine on the Win2k3 box, but I am having trouble mirroring this structure on Solaris.

I checked over the permissions of the ZFS FS/share to make sure I can read and list contents. I also tried creating the ZFS FS/share with a similar name and then creating a symbolic link with the correct name pointing at that new folder but didn't have any luck there either...

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I don't think ZFS supports the ability to host one ZFS filesystem with a set of properties inside another ZFS filesystem. Could very well be wrong though, I await correction from those who may know for certain...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after some more Googling it looks like I have found an answer to my question. CIFS sharing on a ZFS file system is not able to traverse nested ZFS file systems...

http://mail.opensolaris.org/pipermail/cifs-discuss/2008-August/000589.html

An old link, but I am unable to find anything saying otherwise. Looks like I'll have to flatten the folder structure to get around this limitation.